# Python: __subclasses__ order

Tags: python, subclass

I have some code that creates a list of (instances of) subclasses by calling the `__subclasses__()` function on a base class.

```
subclasses = [subclass() for subsclass in BaseClass.__subclasses__()]
```

In Python 2.7 the order of the subclasses in this list is always equal to the order of the import statements in my code (each subclass is defined in it's own Python file). But in Python 3.5 the order of subclasses in this list seems random. Can I use some kind of workaround to get the same behavior in Python 3.5?

See the [`class.__subclasses__` documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#class.__subclasses__).

Comment: Can you say more about why you need the same order. It will help us find the best solution.

Comment: Needing the objects to be implicitly in the same order as a series of imports seems fragile.

Comment: Yes I know it's fragile, but it was a simple solution. The code is from search tool, and the order of subclasses defines the order of search results shown to the end user.

Comment: ick, I got my tags mixed up and looked at 3.x code when I thought I was reading 2.7 code. In 2.x it is indeed a list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 3.5, there is not, not by any trivial means. [As of Python 3.4](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/84745ab464f9195192d741f79407b06daa4eba29) the `tp_subclasses` data structure tracks subclasses via a dictionary (mapping the `id()` value of the subclass to a weak reference, see [Python issue #17936](https://bugs.python.org/issue17936) for why). Dictionaries are unordered.

In Python 3.6, the internal implementation of dictionaries was changed, and they now track insertion order. When you upgrade to Python 3.6, you'd get your subclasses in insertion order (order in which they are first seen by Python) again.

However, the fact that subclasses are tracked in a dictionary is an implementation detail and should not really be relied upon.

You could track the order by some other means. You could give your base class a metaclass that records subclasses in order, for example:

```
from itertools import count
from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary

class SubclassesInOrderMeta(type):
    _subclass_order = WeakKeyDictionary()
    _counter = count()

    def __ordered_subclasses__(cls):
        # sort subclasses by their 'seen' order; the sort key
        # puts classes that are missing from the _subclass_order
        # mapping at the end, defensively.
        order_get = type(cls)._subclass_order.get
        sort_key = lambda c: order_get(c, float('inf'))
        return sorted(cls.__subclasses__(), key=sort_key)

    def __new__(mcls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls = super(SubclassesInOrderMeta, mcls).__new__(mcls, *args, **kwargs)
        mcls._subclass_order[cls] = next(mcls._counter)
        return cls
```

Comment: Thanks! But it gives the following error: TypeError: __ordered_subclasses__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls'

Comment: After adding '@classmethod' to the method __ordered_subclasses__ it complains about AttributeError: type object 'type' has no attribute '_subclass_order', on line order_get = type(cls)._subclass_order.get. Any advice?

Comment: @compie: why are you adding that to the method? It's a method *on the metatype*, not on the classes (which are effectively instances of the metatype). If you make it a classmethod, you don't have access to the class object anymore, so you can't even call `cls.__subclasses__()` anymore.

Comment: @compie: put differently: you can't make this a `@classmethod` and still have it work.

Comment: It was an error on my side. I forgot to use 'metaclass='. The problem is solved now. Thanks!